# How to fix a not defined javascript error?

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, setcookie

I am fairly new to Javascript and what I am trying to do is have a cookie set as soon as I click on a link. When I return back to the previous page from the link, I want the page to auto refresh and notify the user by color to show what link they just clicked. I used this example to guide me http://webdesign.about.com/od/cookies/a/aa083198.htm. But I am still not getting it.

The code below is what I have. The problem is that as soon as I click on the link firebug brings up the error "getLink not defined". Also through web developer on Firefox, it seems that my cookie is not actually being set even though I am calling it from the Html.I am also showing gave the most important part in my Html that calls the function.

The videoId i have in setCookie is a php variable that is defined somewhere else in my code. I would really appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

```
   <head>
    <script language="text/javascript">
    var cookie_name = "watched";
        function setCookie(cookie_name,cookie_value)
        {

        if (document.cookie!="") {
           index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name);
           } else {
            index = -1;
            }
            if (index == -1) {
              var finish = 7200;
              var cookie_value = videoId + "; expires=" + finish;
              document.cookie=cookie_name  + "=" + cookie_value;
              }         
            }

     function getLink(cookie_value) {     
       if (document.cookie) {
         index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_value);
             if (index != -1) {
             colorLinks;
              }
            else{
            //alert("No color");
             }

              }
            return colorLinks;
           }

     function colorLinks()
      {
        $('#' + videoId).css('background-color: pink'); 

      }
  </script>
  </head>
<body onLoad=window.refresh>
<div id="page">
echo '<a href="' . $link . '" onclick="setCookie(); return true;">' . $this->Links
```

Comment: Which line does the error message point to? You're not calling `getLink()` anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: *The videoId i have in setCookie is a php variable that is defined somewhere else in my code.* - have you set the variable in JavaScript as well? JavaScript isn't automatically aware of PHP variables.

Comment: where did you call getLink function?

Comment: um yeah that's where the confusion is for me. I don't know If I'm meant to be calling getLink or setCookie as I click on the link. Silly I know but I'm really confused.

Comment: @Juhana no I havent, how do I do that?

Comment: @user875139 You could set an input type="hidden" with the value param equal to videoId php var

Comment: Frankly, I think you should drop down to JavaScript basics before coming back to cookies. Your current code seems to have so many issues it'd take quite a lot of effort to debug the whole thing.

Comment: Wow its that bad? As I said I'm a beginner and I mean you cant try without the possibility of failing right? I just need some pointers, that's why i cam here. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: the problem is that you don't seem to know the basic of interaction between javascript and php, and you're trying something a little bit complicate for a beginner. You should read some doc or tuto and get back to this code.

Comment: Fair answer I will go back and let you guys know what I came up with. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This does not make sense:

```
function getLink(cookie_value) {  
  if (document.cookie) {
    index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_value);
    if (index != -1) {
      colorLinks; // you mean colorLinks(); ???
    }
    else {
      //alert("No color");
    }
  }
 // why return a function that sets color instead of just calling it?
  return colorLinks;
}
```

and there is luckily nothing called `window.refresh` (unless you have created it yourself) or you would loop forever

Comment: My research lead me to that window.refresh find. Guess you cant trust everything you see on the internet. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the code i don't see where `videoId` is given a value
2. You don't call the function `setCookie(cookie_name,cookie_value);` to set the cookie.

Please read about cookies: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Aaahh i see that one, thanks for the notice, il change and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try to get my head wrapped around this.